# jQuery Select next instance of a class

Tags: jquery, css

Here is the HTML I'm working with:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="section">
    <div class="details"></div>
</div>
<div class="section">
    <div class="details"></div>
</div>
<div class="section">
    <div class="details"></div>
</div>
</div> <!-- end container -->
```

From within any given (.'details'), I need to be able to target the next ('.details').

I had this working for selecting the next .section:

```
jQuery(this).nextAll('.section').first().css('background-color', 'red');
```

But I can't seem to find out how to select the instance of .details within the section.

Thanks

Comment: If you're already selecting the section, then you can just select the details div inside with `.find(".details")`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to tweak it a little bit.

```
jQuery(this).nextAll('.section .details').first('.details' )css('background-color', 'red');
```